# REGEX - Extract OU from Distinguished Name

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, extract, distinguishedname

I need to extract "OU" part from my Distinguished Name with REGEX.

For exemple :

```
"CN=DAVID Jean Louis (a),OU=Coiffeur,OU=France,DC=Paris,DC=France"

"CN=PROVOST Franck,OU=Coiffeur,OU=France,DC=Paris,DC=France"

"CN=SZHARCOFF Michel (AB),OU=Coiffeur_Inter,OU=France,DC=Paris,DC=France"
```

I need to have

```
"OU=Coiffeur,OU=France"  

"OU=Coiffeur,OU=France"

"OU=Coiffeur_Inter,OU=France"
```

I try `"CN=SZHARCOFF Michel (AB),OU=Coiffeur_Inter,OU=France,DC=Paris,DC=France" -match "^CN=[\w-()]*[\w]*"`
But doesn't succeed

Comment: What is the code you try the regex with?

Comment: the code is : `"CN=DAVID Jean Louis (a),OU=Coiffeur,OU=France,DC=Paris,DC=France" -matche "^CN=[\w-()]*[\w]*"`

Comment: So, you tried to match `CN=...` at the start of the string. I thought you used a `-replace`.

Comment: It's just because it's start with CN. 
I have something like this : `"^CN=[\w-()]*\,(?<DN>OU=[\w,]+),"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match all the `OU=` + 1 or more non-comma substrings with `\bOU=[^,]+` regex and then join them with `,`:

```
$matches = [regex]::matches($s, '\bOU=[^,]+') | % { $_.value }
$res = $matches -join ','
```

Output for the first string:

```
OU=Coiffeur,OU=France
```

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary to only match `OU` as a whole word
- `OU=`  - a literal substring
- `[^,]+` - 1 or more (`+`) characters other than (as `[^...]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)) a comma.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIxB7M/1).

Comment: Thanks ! I understand but is it possible to join 2 OU with 1 regex ?

Comment: @P0werSh3ell Regex does not join texts, it only matches parts of/full strings that match the pattern. It is not possible to match discontinuous texts within one match operation. Thus, you either use multiple matching and then joining, or you may also get it using a single replace operation. The replacing approach is usually more cumbersome than matching and joining.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will support DistinguishedName properties containing commas, and provides named groups for matches.  I use this in PowerShell to parse an ADObject's parent DN, etc.

```
^(?:(?<cn>CN=(?<name>.*?)),)?(?<parent>(?:(?<path>(?:CN|OU).*?),)?(?<domain>(?:DC=.*)+))$
```

See Regexr demo: https://regexr.com/5bt64

Comment: Great regex! Thank you!